# TSQL 2 Queries in 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

First, I'll claim no extreme expertise in SQL.

What I am trying to do is pull down some incident counts from a SQL Server database based on a couple of varying criteria and put them into SSRS in a line chart that shows monthly counts on top of each other.  Both of the queries that I had initially created pull down the right data but SSRS will not allow for using multiple data sets on one chart.  This is where I get hung up.  I'm sure I can do some sort of sub-querying to get both data sets into one just separating the counts into columns, but what I've tried thus far aggregates the entire counts.

The data I need is the reporteddate which is a date/time value and a count of incidents that occurred (no need to aggregate the counts, or shouldn't be, since SSRS will allow me to group them by month, which is what the report should look like) matching each of the 2 criteria.

Below are the two queries that I am using:

```
SELECT DISTINCT v_Incident.ReportedDate, COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM            v_Incident INNER JOIN
                         v_IncidentMaxWorkLog_Category ON v_Incident.IncidentID = v_IncidentMaxWorkLog_Category.Incident_Number
WHERE        (v_Incident.Summary LIKE N'Intelligent Incident for Impacted CI%') AND (v_Incident.CustomerFirstName = N'BMC') AND 
                         (v_Incident.CustomerLastName = N'Impact Manager') AND (v_IncidentMaxWorkLog_Category.WORK_LOG_TYPE IN ('General Information', 'Incident Task / Action', 
                         'Working Log')) AND (v_Incident.ReportedDate >= '7/1/2014') AND (v_Incident.ReportedDate >= DATEADD(year, - 1, GETDATE()))
GROUP BY v_Incident.ReportedDate
FROM v_Incident
```

Second Query

```
SELECT DISTINCT v_Incident.ReportedDate, COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM            v_Incident INNER JOIN
                         v_IncidentMaxWorkLog_Category ON v_Incident.IncidentID = v_IncidentMaxWorkLog_Category.Incident_Number
WHERE        (v_Incident.Summary LIKE N'Intelligent Incident for Impacted CI%') AND (v_Incident.CustomerFirstName = N'BMC') AND 
                         (v_Incident.CustomerLastName = N'Impact Manager') AND (v_Incident.ReportedDate >= '7/1/2014') AND (v_Incident.ReportedDate >= DATEADD(year, - 1, GETDATE()))
GROUP BY v_Incident.ReportedDate
FROM v_Incident
```

As you can see, I am pulling down the reporteddate and a count.  If I simply bring those two statements together in a single statement [select (query1) as filtered, (query2) as base] and move the group by's to the outside, I get results, but it is the entire total for each value on every single line, and about 10k lines too many.

Is there a simple solution that will get me each date, and a single count for base and filtered using these 2 or similar queries?  Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: So do you want the results split by the query results or combined? As in, if query 1 returns `1/1/2014, 10` and query 2 returns `1/1/2014, 20` do you want `1/1/2014, 30` or do you want it to show the duplicates?

Comment: It should be separated, so if query 1 returns 1/1/2014, 10 and query 2 returns 1/1/2014, 20 it should output 1/1/2014 BASE: 10 FILTERED: 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your queries are quite similar.  It looks like you have a total count, and then a partial count of some records that have specific work log types.  Here is a query that returns date, BaseCount, and 'WorkLogFilteredCount'  SSRS should be able to consume the date as an axis and the other two columns as separate series very easily for your chart.

```
SELECT  v_Incident.ReportedDate
        , COUNT(*) AS BaseCount
        , SUM(CASE WHEN v_IncidentMaxWorkLog_Category.WORK_LOG_TYPE IN ('General Information', 'Incident Task / Action', 'Working Log') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS WorkLogFilteredCount

FROM    v_Incident
        INNER JOIN v_IncidentMaxWorkLog_Category
            ON v_Incident.IncidentID = v_IncidentMaxWorkLog_Category.Incident_Number
WHERE   (v_Incident.Summary LIKE N'Intelligent Incident for Impacted CI%')
        AND (v_Incident.CustomerFirstName = N'BMC')
        AND (v_Incident.CustomerLastName = N'Impact Manager')
        AND (v_Incident.ReportedDate >= '7/1/2014')
        AND (v_Incident.ReportedDate >= DATEADD(year, - 1, GETDATE()))
GROUP BY v_Incident.ReportedDate
FROM v_Incident
```

Comment: This looks especially effective to use, including if I need to make a change to the requirements in the future.  However, when I try to execute the query I receive a syntax error for the first FROM statement.  Any thoughts?  Based on my understanding of t-sql this looks correct.  The management studio is also reporting that SUM isn't a built in function, but it's not erroring on that when I try to execute the query.

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.

Comment: I had put the ) at the wrong spot, but it is missing from the end of your case statement, with it in the correct location this statement works quite efficiently.  The only thing I will need to do to get this to the end state is not tally the counts up together.  For every worklogfiltered entry I have 2 fullcount entries, and it really should just be 1.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I am thinking you want I am going to use a [UNION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx) and treat the unioned queries as a [subquery](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189575(v=sql.105).aspx).

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    ((SELECT DISTINCT 
          v_Incident.ReportedDate, COUNT(*) AS Count, 'BASE' as [Designator]
      FROM            
          v_Incident 
      INNER JOIN
          v_IncidentMaxWorkLog_Category ON v_Incident.IncidentID = v_IncidentMaxWorkLog_Category.Incident_Number
      WHERE        
         (v_Incident.Summary LIKE N'Intelligent Incident for Impacted CI%') 
         AND (v_Incident.CustomerFirstName = N'BMC') 
         AND (v_Incident.CustomerLastName = N'Impact Manager') 
         AND (v_IncidentMaxWorkLog_Category.WORK_LOG_TYPE IN ('General Information', 'Incident Task / Action', 'Working Log')) 
         AND (v_Incident.ReportedDate >= '7/1/2014') 
         AND (v_Incident.ReportedDate >= DATEADD(year, - 1, GETDATE()))
     GROUP BY 
         v_Incident.ReportedDate
FROM v_Incident)

UNION ALL

(SELECT DISTINCT v_Incident.ReportedDate, COUNT(*) AS Count, 'Filtered' as [Designator]
FROM            v_Incident INNER JOIN
                         v_IncidentMaxWorkLog_Category ON v_Incident.IncidentID = v_IncidentMaxWorkLog_Category.Incident_Number
WHERE        (v_Incident.Summary LIKE N'Intelligent Incident for Impacted CI%') AND (v_Incident.CustomerFirstName = N'BMC') AND 
                         (v_Incident.CustomerLastName = N'Impact Manager') AND (v_Incident.ReportedDate >= '7/1/2014') AND (v_Incident.ReportedDate >= DATEADD(year, - 1, GETDATE()))
GROUP BY v_Incident.ReportedDate
FROM v_Incident)) ORDER BY ReportedDate, Designator
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select isnull(a.ReportedDate, b.ReportedDate) ReportedDate, 
       a.Count ACount, b.Count BCount
from
(
    SELECT DISTINCT v_Incident.ReportedDate, COUNT(*) AS Count
    FROM            v_Incident INNER JOIN
                             v_IncidentMaxWorkLog_Category ON v_Incident.IncidentID = v_IncidentMaxWorkLog_Category.Incident_Number
    WHERE        (v_Incident.Summary LIKE N'Intelligent Incident for Impacted CI%') AND (v_Incident.CustomerFirstName = N'BMC') AND 
                             (v_Incident.CustomerLastName = N'Impact Manager') AND (v_IncidentMaxWorkLog_Category.WORK_LOG_TYPE IN ('General Information', 'Incident Task / Action', 
                             'Working Log')) AND (v_Incident.ReportedDate >= '7/1/2014') AND (v_Incident.ReportedDate >= DATEADD(year, - 1, GETDATE()))
    GROUP BY v_Incident.ReportedDate
    FROM v_Incident
) a
full outer join
(
    SELECT DISTINCT v_Incident.ReportedDate, COUNT(*) AS Count
    FROM            v_Incident INNER JOIN
                             v_IncidentMaxWorkLog_Category ON v_Incident.IncidentID = v_IncidentMaxWorkLog_Category.Incident_Number
    WHERE        (v_Incident.Summary LIKE N'Intelligent Incident for Impacted CI%') AND (v_Incident.CustomerFirstName = N'BMC') AND 
                             (v_Incident.CustomerLastName = N'Impact Manager') AND (v_Incident.ReportedDate >= '7/1/2014') AND (v_Incident.ReportedDate >= DATEADD(year, - 1, GETDATE()))
    GROUP BY v_Incident.ReportedDate
    FROM v_Incident
) b on b.ReportedDate = a.ReportedDate
```

This treats each of your original queries, and puts them as a 'table' into a third query which joins them on ReportedDate. It uses a Full Outer Join, so that if a b is missing the a will still be retrieved and also if an a is missing then the b will still be reported. This way there are 3 combinations:

- a is there, b is null
- a and b are there
- a is null, b is there
  Thus, to get the ReportedDate in the result use isnull to show a.ReportedDate and is that's null (case 3 above) use b.ReportedDate.

Remember, in any SQL Select, you can replace a table name with a Select query.